# I can't find a way to create a simple multidimensional array or hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby

You Ruby pros will laugh but I'm having such a hard time with this. I've searched and searched and tried a lot of different things but nothing seems right. I guess I'm just used to dealing with arrays in js and php. Here is what I want to do; consider this pseudo code:

```
i = 0
foreach (items as item) {
  myarray[i]['title'] = item['title']
  myarray[i]['desc'] = item['desc']
  i++
}
```

Right, so then I can loop through myarray or access 'title' and 'desc' by the index (i). Simplest thing in the world. I've found a few ways to make it work in Ruby but they've all been really messy or confusing. I want to know the right way to do it, and the cleanest.

Comment: look at http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index - maybe it's what you look for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are actually updating `my_array` (which implies that there is probably a better way to do this), you probably want map instead:

```
items = [
  {'title' => 't1', 'desc' => 'd1', 'other' => 'o1'},
  {'title' => 't2', 'desc' => 'd2', 'other' => 'o2'},
  {'title' => 't3', 'desc' => 'd3', 'other' => 'o3'},
]

my_array = items.map do |item|
  {'title' => item['title'], 'desc' => item['desc'] }
end

items    # => [{"title"=>"t1", "desc"=>"d1", "other"=>"o1"}, {"title"=>"t2", "desc"=>"d2", "other"=>"o2"}, {"title"=>"t3", "desc"=>"d3", "other"=>"o3"}]
my_array # => [{"title"=>"t1", "desc"=>"d1"}, {"title"=>"t2", "desc"=>"d2"}, {"title"=>"t3", "desc"=>"d3"}]
```

Comment: Ahh terrific. This answer is really helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why you are trying to do this, as it seems like `items` is already an array with hashes inside it, and in my code below, `myarray` is exactly the same as `items`.

Try using `each_with_index` instead of a `foreach` loop:

```
items.each_with_index do |item, index|
  myarray[index] = item
end
```

If you have extra attributes in each item, such as a `id` or something, then you would want to remove those extra attributes before you add the item to `myarray`.

Comment: Edit: Ohhhh I get it, I think that will work. Thank you! Before edit: Thanks man, that makes sense. But is there a way to add a set of keys for each index like myarray[index]['title'] and myarray[index]['desc'] or am I not understanding how this works in Ruby? If there is a way to do it, how do I initialize the array? That part is boggling my mind as well, as myarray = Array.new doesn't seem to be enough.

Comment: @KeithCollins Actually, can you post what `items` contains in your question? The code I posted doesn't really do anything right now, I added a note at the top about it.

Comment: Right, I'm trying to create a clean array that has some stuff from items, some stuff from elsewhere. Like you said, I guess I could remove the stuff I don't want from items, but removing each individually would be a pain. So my preference would still be something like myarray[index]['title'] = item['title'] etc etc

Comment: To filter the keys allowed in items, you can use the `select` method: `myarray[index] = item.select { |key, value| ["title", "desc"].include?(key) }`

Answer (score 0):

```
titles = ["t1", "t2", "t3"]
 descs = ["d1", "d2", "d3"]

h= Hash.new

titles.each.with_index{ |v,i| h[i] = {title: "#{v}" } }

puts h[0][:title] #=> t1
puts h            #=>  {0=>{:title=>"t1"}, 1=>{:title=>"t2"}...}

descs.each.with_index{ |v,i| h[i] = h[i].merge( {desc: "#{v}" } ) }

puts h[0][:desc] #=> d1
puts h           #=>  {0=>{:title=>"t1", :desc=>"d1"}, 1=>...
```